# Getting boxes instead of text in webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I am loading a URL in web view its successfully loading , but all text in web page appears has boxes.

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);     
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl(url);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

boxes means it appears as squares 
the language is different its not English , how i can display that in webview.

Comment: What do you mean by "Boxes"?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?? Give in detail with code..

Comment: Make sure your page encoding is correct. http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations

Comment: seems like fonts are not supported...

Comment: all the text appears as squares

Comment: ya the language is different its not English how i can display that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do that you have to generate webfont for te font if its not English..

To generate web font look at this url:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator